# How to deal with default values in (deeply) nested function calls?

Tags: c++, default-value

Suppose there is a function with a default value:

```
int foo(int x=42);
```

If this is called by others like this:

```
int bar(int x=42) { return foo(x); }
int moo(int x=42) { return bar(x); }
```

This is of course just a contrived example. However, I sometimes have a quite similar situation. The parameter is just passed from the highest level (`moo`) to the lowest and only there it is actually used. The bad thing about this is that when I change `foo` to have a default different than `42` I would have to search for all callers and change the default value accordingly.

**Is there some pattern/idiom to avoid this situation?**

The only simple solution that comes to my mind is

```
int bar()      { return foo(); }
int bar(int x) { return foo(x); }
```

However, as I am a bit lazy and in real code this would lead to quite some code duplication, I would like to avoid this.

Comment: I would argue that you shouldn't really be using the parameter default value for arbitrary defaults. For those I would use namespaced const variables. Parameter defaults are good for things like *sane* initialization values (zero / nullptr / false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The practical general solutions include:

- Use an `Optional_` class for the argument, such as `boost::optional` or a DIY equivalent.
- Name the default value (and use the name in the wrapper function definitions).
- Overload each wrapper function, as you've shown in the question.
- Just repeat the default value in the wrapper function definitions, but this breaks the DRY principle, *don't repeat yourself*.

---

In a [comment else-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460227/how-to-deal-with-default-values-in-deeply-nested-function-calls/38460583#comment64325407_38460426) Tobi brings up the case of a wrapper `asdf` defined as

```
int asdf(int x=42,int y=42){ return foo(x)+foo(y);}
```

Using an `Optional_` class:

```
auto foo( Optional_<int> x)
    -> int
{ return (x.is_empty()? 42 : x.value()); }

auto asdf( Optional_<int> x = {}, Optional_<int> y = {} )
    -> int
{ return foo( x ) + foo( y ); }
```

Using a named default value:

```
int const foo_default = 42;

auto foo( int x = foo_default )
    -> int
{ return x; }

auto asdf( int x = foo_default, int y = foo_default )
    -> int
{ return foo( x ) + foo( y ); }
```

Using overloads:

```
auto foo( int x = 42 )
    -> int
{ return x; }

auto asdf()
    -> int
{ return foo() + foo(); }

auto asdf( int x )
    -> int
{ return foo( x ) + foo(); }

auto asdf( int x, int y )
    -> int
{ return foo( x ) + foo( y ); }
```

---

It's worth noting that `asdf` can't be easily defined as a function template forwarding its arguments. Also, such a template can't be easily defined in a separate translation unit, and one can't take its address. For these reasons I did not include this possible solution in the bullet list: it's very constrained, not a general solution.

Comment: `boost::optional` *or* `std::optional` now.

Comment: I am not sure why I didnt realize the option of a named constant myself... sometimes I am just thinking too complicated (even for C++)

Answer (score 6):

I'd advise to select one of these two options below (as you can see in other answers - there are more possible solutions).

1. Overload your functions
2. Define constant

So, option 1 would looks like below:

```
int foo(int x=42);
int bar(int x) { return foo(x); }
int moo(int x) { return bar(x); }
int bar() { return foo(); }
int moo() { return bar(); }
```

And, option 2 will be a little shorter:

```
constexpr int FOO_DEFAULT = 42;
int foo(int x=FOO_DEFAULT);
int bar(int x=FOO_DEFAULT) { return foo(x); }
int moo(int x=FOO_DEFAULT) { return bar(x); }
```

I'd use option-1 for cases with small number of default values (like one default value), option-2 for cases where you have quite a few default values - like `foo(int a, int b = 3, std::string c = "wow", float pi = 3.14)`

Comment: Upvoted in spite of the "You have two options to select", which is incorrect. :)

Comment: On consideration, removed the upvote due to the ALL UPPERCASE identifiers (I didn't notice, sorry). All uppercase is likely to conflict with macro names. So this teaches a for C++ ungood idiom: it's OK in Java, and needed in Python, but very ungood in C++.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I believe OP if use my proposed solution will chose the name according to its own coding standard/style (if have any). BTW - my opinion on this very specific topic is that the very same style should be used for variable-like macros and const variables - because logically - there are the same thing, they are used to achieve the same goal. So this is quite opposite opinion to yours...

Comment: There is a third option: Only give `moo` a default (of course, this only works if `bar` and `foo` are internal functions only.

Comment: Constant variables and macros are indeed used to achieve the same goal, but they are *not* the same thing. The reason you write macros in SCREAMING CASE is because they should be avoided whenever possible and you want them to stand out. Constant vars are, on the other hand, quite reasonable, obey a logical scope, and otherwise follow standard language conventions. There's nothing to be worried about, so they don't need to scream their presence. I saw once in a major coding convention (either Google's or Apple's, I forget which) that they prefix constants with `k`. I liked and have adopted it.

Comment: @CodyGray I hope you do not mind - but I disagree. Indeed macros are not good thing - no difference in opinion here. But there are simpler ways to detect macros than having special convention for them (like searching for `#define`). I like the convention to name thing taking into account its logical role - not its implementation or "nature". There is also practical aspect - when I change macro to constant  - I like the change consists just of one line - not 50 lines; I mean I like to change only definition - not every usage.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the duplication with:

```
template<typename... T>
  auto bar(T&&... t) { return foo(std::forward<T>(t)...); }
```

But that's not an improvement IMHO. Just stop being lazy and define the overloads that call `foo()` when no argument is provided.

Comment: **−1** This changes the nature of `bar`. Now one can't take its address. One can't (practically) implement it in a separately compiled unit. Calling it with ungood number of arguments or types of arguments, one gets template instantiation errors instead of straightforward diagnostics.

Comment: As I said, it's not an improvement. But it **does** avoid the duplication, which is what the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: I think it wont work when I have eg `int asdf(int x=42,int y=42){ return foo(x)+foo(y);}`

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. `foo(x) + foo(y)` is not the same as return `foo(t...)`, nor `(foo(t) + ...)`.